# Proof Disjunctive Syllogism using Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

So, how can I have to prove this using natural deduction:
$\lnot p, p \lor q \vdash q$

What I did is:

1. $\lnot p$
2. $p \lor q$
3. p assumption
4. $\bot$ from 1&3
5. q from 4

Is it ok 100% ? What can I do to make it perfect ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not.

You have a *disjunction* as 2nd premise : thus you have to consider both disjuncts with [$(\lor \text E)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

The first sub-case, with $p$ as assumption, is Ok.

You have to add the second sub-case, with $q$ as assumption, in which case the conclusion $q$ is immediate.

Then, having derived $q$ in both cases, you can use $(\lor \text E)$ and conclude.

---

The flaw in your derivation is that you have the undischarged assumption 3. Thus, what your derivation amounts to is really :

> $¬p, p∨q, p \vdash q$.

Comment: So if I go like this: 
...
6. q assumption
7. q from 5&6
is ok ?

Comment: @RazvanStatescu - correct.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to use a [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to make sure one uses the rules correctly. Here is a proof:

[image]

The first five lines are the same as your proof. However, they only considered the left side, $P$, of the disjunction on line 2. You have to also consider the right side, $Q$. Note how that was done in this proof checker simply by stating the assumption on line 6. Line 6 was also the derivation of the goal.

The justification for line 7 was given as "∨E 2, 3–5, 6–6". That can be understood as using [disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) (∨E) on the disjunction on line 2 noted as "2" in the justification. One side of the disjunction started with an assumption on line 3 and derived the goal, $Q$, on line 5. That subproof was noted as "3-5". The other side of the disjunction started with an assumption on line 6 and since it already was what I wanted to derive I ended the subproof on line 6 as well. This was noted as "6-6".

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 2):

### Proof without ⊥ elimination (or any derived rules).

Sorry for necroposting, but here's a way of solving the proof without the use of a contradiction elimination I couldn't find online.

[image: fitch diagram proof]

Lines 9 and 10 could be combined into one line if instead of introducing the negation on line 9, we eliminated it, but some proof checkers, such as [this](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) one don't seem to support eliminations of this specific form.